# Upload android build (.apk file) on Jenkins just for running automation suite and not build android apk

Tags: android, jenkins

I am integrating my android automation suite with Jenkins. I am successfully able to integrate github repo and appium with Jenkins but don't know where to add android build (.apk file). I have searched on internet and most of the information is how to automate building the app, run tests and release the builds on Google Play Store. Here, I don't want to build the android app, just want to run automation suite on already available android build on my local computer. Is there any way I can upload that android build on Jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way. To do this, add path of the apk file that resides inside the project in appium.app property in serenity.properties file. In my case it is

```
appium.app = D:\\{project_name}\\app-release-12-08-21-02.apk
```

As I run my tests in real device and the apk file is installed on it as well so it runs smoothly. No extra setup is required